# Objective-C: Get list of subclasses from superclass

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C is there a way to ask a Class if there are any Subclass implementations.

I have a Base class which has multiple subclasses. I would like to loop through all the subclasses and perform a class selector on each of them.

**Edit**:

I have a set of classes that can process certain types of data. Each of the processors subclass a base class that provides methods that each processor needs.

Each class knows what data it can process and some classes can process certain types of data better than others.

I would like to have a class method on each class that would provide a response back to a factory class that says yes i can process that data, and give a indication of how well it can process it.

The factory would then make the decision on which class to instantiate based on which class says it can process the data the best.

I have also found this question from 2009 (I did search before I posted this but didn't find anything) [Discover subclasses of a given class in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810628/discover-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-obj-c).

**Edit 2**:

The `+ (void)load` method looks to be the perfect solution to what I am looking for. So I now have the following:

```
+ (void)registerSubclass:(Class)subclass {
    NSLog(@"Registered %@", subclass);
}
```

In my base class the this is my subs.

```
+(void)load {
    [BaseSwitch registerSubclass:[self class]];
}
```

This now displays a debug message for each of the subclasses.

My next question is (probably a stupid one), how do I store the classes that get registered in the registerSubclass method. Is there a way to have class variable that I can read later?

**Edit 3**:

Found some example code here [A simple, extensible HTTP server in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html)

Which has left me with the following, seems pretty simple after all is said and done. But I thought I would put it here for future reference.

```
@implementation BaseSwitch

static NSMutableArray *registeredSubclasses;

+ (void)registerSubclass:(Class)subclass {
    if (registeredSubclasses == nil) {
        registeredSubclasses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [registeredSubclasses addObject:subclass];

    NSLog(@"Registered %@", subclass);
}

+ (void)logSubclasses {
    for (int i = 0; i < [registeredSubclasses count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [registeredSubclasses objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}

@end
```

Thanks for everyones suggestions, I will leave the question unanswered for a couple more days incase something else comes up.

Comment: Why can’t you use Mike’s suggestion in that question you’ve linked? Have your superclass expose an API for registering (sub)classes for data types, and have each subclass use that API to tell the superclass which data types it can handle. This could also be exported by a different class instead of the superclass.

Comment: @Bavarious, that is probably the way I will go. But I am interested to see if there are any other ways.

Comment: You are far, far, better off having the classes registered somehow.  Dynamic discovery is attractive, but Objective-C really just wasn't designed for such patterns.   Explicit registration also has the advantage of there being one spot or one simple string you can search for to yield an inventory of all registrants.

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from using the Observer design pattern in this instance.  Have you explored coding your project that way?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You can never list subclasses of a class. In (almost) any programming language. This is one of the basic properties of Object Oriented Programming.

Consider changing your object model.

What you probably want is to create an abstract class and different subclasses but you shouldn't access the subclasses from the abstract class. You should create another object (Factory class) which registers the subclasses and selects the appropiate one when needed.

Note that you cannot efficiently register a class from the class itself. For a class code to be executed, the class has to be loaded first. That means, you have to import its header in some other class and that means that you are actually registering the class by importing its header.
There are two possible solutions:

1. Your factory class has to know the names of all subclasses (either at compile time or reading some configuration file).
2. Your factory class has a method to which anyone can pass the name of a class to be registered. This is the right solution if you want external libraries to register a new subclass. Then you can put the subclass registration code into the main header of the library.

Comment: It is not possible to list every possible subclass of a class, but there is no property of OOP that prevents listing the subclasses that exist within a given program at a given point of time. In ObjC, this can be done with `objc_getClassList()` and then introspecting the classes. It's not a good idea, but nothing about OOP prohibits it.

Comment: You are right but certainly it is against the principles of OOP to do it from the superclass :) However, the classes has to be loaded somewhere and you need to know their names (or the files when they are defined) to load them.

Comment: @Sulthan how is it "against the principles" and why would it matter what file they are declared in? The runtime has a list of classes, you can query it however you want. Every dynamic language I've ever worked with has had this basic feature.

Answer (score 14):

This function gives you all subclasses of a class:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSArray *ClassGetSubclasses(Class parentClass)
{
  int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
  Class *classes = NULL;

  classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
  numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);

  NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numClasses; i++)
  {
    Class superClass = classes[i];
    do
    {
      superClass = class_getSuperclass(superClass);
    } while(superClass && superClass != parentClass);

    if (superClass == nil)
    {
      continue;
    }

    [result addObject:classes[i]];
  }

  free(classes);

  return result;
}
```

Taken from [Cocoa with Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html).

Comment: @ravoorinandan I think what you mean is that it isn't compiling for ARC. I've updated it for ARC support.

Comment: @ ThomasW thanks a lot. Will try it and let you know. :)

Comment: I've made [this Class Hierarchy Logger](https://github.com/sebaven/class-hierarchy-logger) that uses an approach similar to the one that @ThomasW suggested and then loops through the subclasses. It might be useful if you need more insight on how to iterate the subclass hierarchy. I hope it helps!

Comment: the problem with that, as described by author is that does not give you the subclass casted at runtime, but all subclasses i.e. (MySubClass*)MyParentClass.

Comment: Works, but be careful when using. It took around 60ms for me to get the class list with objc_getClassList.

Answer (score 1):

The example from [Cocoa with Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html) can lead to EXC_I386_GPFLT, which stands for General Protection Fault. Instead of the do while loop, we should use a normal while loop to check if the `superClass` is valid.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSArray * ClassGetSubclasses(Class parentClass)
{
    int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);

    // According to the docs of objc_getClassList we should check
    // if numClasses is bigger than 0.
    if (numClasses <= 0) {
        return [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    int memSize = sizeof(Class) * numClasses;
    Class *classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(memSize);

    if (classes == NULL && memSize) {
        return [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);

    NSMutableArray<Class> *result = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        Class superClass = classes[i];

        // Don't add the parent class to list of sublcasses
        if (superClass == parentClass) {
            continue;
        }

        // Using a do while loop, like pointed out in Cocoa with Love,
        // can lead to EXC_I386_GPFLT, which stands for General
        // Protection Fault and means we are doing something we
        // shouldn't do. It's safer to use a regular while loop to
        // check if superClass is valid.
        while (superClass && superClass != parentClass) {
            superClass = class_getSuperclass(superClass);
        }

        if (superClass) {
            [result addObject:classes[i]];
        }
    }

    free(classes);

    return result;
}
```

Check out the following GitHub issues for reference:

- [Sentry Cocoa](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/issues/1395)
- [One Signal iOS SDK](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/issues/278)