# List all subclasses of one class

Tags: swift, reflection

Can I return a list of all subclasses of one class? For example:

```
class Mother {

}

class ChildFoo: Mother {

}

class ChildBar: Mother {

}

let motherSubclasses = ... // TODO
print(motherSubclasses) // should to return [ChildFoo.self, ChildBar.self]
```

Comment: I don't believe this will be possible without delving into the Obj-C runtime – [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923586/objective-c-get-list-of-subclasses-from-superclass) will probably be a good starting place. Although I would question *why* exactly you want to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surprisingly the Objective-C runtime functions work just as well with Swift classes, even if they don't subclass from `NSObject`. Further, all classes in Swift seems to derive from `SwiftObject`. `SwiftObject` itself does not have a superclass.

First, a wrapper structure to handle the ObjC runtime functions:

```
import Foundation

struct ClassInfo : CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {
    let classObject: AnyClass
    let className: String

    init?(_ classObject: AnyClass?) {
        guard classObject != nil else { return nil }

        self.classObject = classObject!

        let cName = class_getName(classObject)!
        self.className = String(cString: cName)
    }

    var superclassInfo: ClassInfo? {
        let superclassObject: AnyClass? = class_getSuperclass(self.classObject)
        return ClassInfo(superclassObject)
    }

    var description: String {
        return self.className
    }

    static func ==(lhs: ClassInfo, rhs: ClassInfo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.className == rhs.className
    }
}
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
class Mother { }
class ChildFoo: Mother { }
class ChildBar: Mother { }

class AnIrrelevantClass { }

let motherClassInfo = ClassInfo(Mother.self)!
var subclassList = [ClassInfo]()

var count = UInt32(0)
let classList = objc_copyClassList(&count)!

for i in 0..<Int(count) {
    if let classInfo = ClassInfo(classList[i]),
        let superclassInfo = classInfo.superclassInfo,
        superclassInfo == motherClassInfo
    {
        subclassList.append(classInfo)
    }
}

print(subclassList)
```

This only performs a shallow search so it won't sweep up grandchildren classes but you get the idea.

Comment: `SwiftObject` doesn't inherit from `NSObject`, but it *does* conform to `NSObjectProtocol`, which allows it to be available in the Obj-C runtime.

Comment: But how to use Objective-C runtime functions? I [get some erros](http://i.imgur.com/NN66T3y.png). I tried, but I could not.

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: It's work!! Thank you. I didn't know the objective-c runtime functions.

Comment: Hey, I made some changes in your code to list all classes that subscriber a protocol: https://gist.github.com/brunomacabeusbr/eea343bb9119b96eed3393e41dcda0c9 Maybe you think it's cool

Comment: This doesn't work when trying to find a subclasses of a Generic type, I'm guessing because they're not exposed to Objective-C. Any way to do that?

Comment: You don't need force unwrap in `class_getName(classObject)!`

Comment: New link to code that list all classes that subscriber a protocol: https://gist.github.com/macabeus/eea343bb9119b96eed3393e41dcda0c9

Comment: This crashes with iOS 13.4, XCode 11.4. Answer: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853427/objc-copyclasslist-crash-exc-bad-instruction-after-update-to-ios-13-4-xcode-1/60854056#60854056

Comment: It (and the other solution) crash for me on iOS 15 (including the gist above)

Answer (score 5):

An optimised version of Jean Le Moignan's code

```
    static func subclasses<T>(of theClass: T) -> [T] {
        var count: UInt32 = 0, result: [T] = []
        let allClasses = objc_copyClassList(&count)!
        let classPtr = address(of: theClass)

        for n in 0 ..< count {
            let someClass: AnyClass = allClasses[Int(n)]
            guard let someSuperClass = class_getSuperclass(someClass), address(of: someSuperClass) == classPtr else { continue }
            result.append(someClass as! T)
        }

        return result
    }
```

```
public func address(of object: Any?) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer{
    return Unmanaged.passUnretained(object as AnyObject).toOpaque()
}
```

For every Type there is only one metaclass instance in runtime, so, pointers on them are unique.
In some reason operator `===` is not allowed for AnyClass, but we can compare pointers directly

performance test:

```
        let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        let found = RuntimeUtils.subclasses(of:UIViewController.self)
        let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
        print("Took \(diff) seconds, \(found.count) found")
```

output:

String(describing: theClass): 
`Took 1.0465459823608398 seconds, 174 found`

address(of: theClass):
`Took 0.2642860412597656 seconds, 174 found`

Comment: Shouldn't you call `allClasses.free()` before `return result`? From the apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418762-objc_copyclasslist): "Return Value
A nil terminated array of classes. You must free the array with free()."

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variant based on Code Different's previous answer, but shorter:

```
func subclasses<T>(of theClass: T) -> [T] {
    var count: UInt32 = 0, result: [T] = []
    let allClasses = objc_copyClassList(&count)!

    for n in 0 ..< count {
        let someClass: AnyClass = allClasses[Int(n)]
        guard let someSuperClass = class_getSuperclass(someClass), String(describing: someSuperClass) == String(describing: theClass) else { continue }
        result.append(someClass as! T)
    }

    return result
}
```

The return type will be according to the receiving variable type, thanks to generics.

I wanted to write this as an extension to AnyClass... but unfortunately Swift doesn't allow it.

Comment: String(describing: someSuperClass) is pretty slow, but for every class there is only one metaclass (class type) instance.

So, you can compare pointers on metaclasses instead

Answer (score 0):

Result returned by objc_copyClassList is no longer enumerable.
This works:

```
public func subclasses<T>(of theClass: T) -> [T] {
    var count: UInt32 = 0, result: [T] = []
    let classList = objc_copyClassList(&count)!
    defer { free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(classList)) }
    let classes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: classList, count: Int(count))
    let classPtr = address(of: theClass)

    for someClass in classes {
        guard let someSuperClass = class_getSuperclass(someClass), address(of: someSuperClass) == classPtr else { continue }
        result.append(someClass as! T)
    }

    return result
}

public func address(of object: Any?) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return Unmanaged.passUnretained(object as AnyObject).toOpaque()
}
```