# Initialize subclasses from json

Tags: json, swift, inheritance, swift-protocols

I am looking for a good way of persisting arbitrary subclasses.

I am writing objects [`asDictionary` to json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893370/237509) upon save, and [`init(json)` them back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727346/237509) upon load. The structure is `Group`s that have `Unit`s of different kind. The `Group` only knows its units as something implementing `UnitProtocol`.

[image: Groups and Units]

The subclasses `UA` etc of `Unit` has the exact same data as a Unit. So data wise, the `asDictionary` and `init(json)` fits well in `Unit`. The subclasses only differ in logic. So when restoring them from file, I believe it has to be the exact subclass that is initialized.

## (Bad) Solutions I thought of

1. Letting every group know that it can have Units of different subclasses by not holding them as `[UnitProtocol]` only, but also as `[UA]`, `[UB]`, etc, that can saved separately, restored by their respective sub inits, and be merged into a `[UnitProtocol]` upon init.
2. Store subunits with their classname and create a `Unit.Init(json)` that somehow is able to pass down the initialization depending on subtype.
3. ?? Still thinking, but I believe there has to be something I can learn here to do this in a maintainable way without breaking the single responsibility policy.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding `NSKeyedArchiver`, which handles all of this transparently? JSON seems a lot of work for no benefit if the only goal is to save and restore objects.

Comment: Reason: Not knowing about it. How do I use it? If you mean "why json?" is because I like json when the data leaves iOS and goes cloudy.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i

Comment: Note that Swift 4 will have an even more powerful solution. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0167-swift-encoders.md (but it won't be available for a couple of months or so)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "goes cloudy" here. Do you actually need to post it to a service that requires JSON? (iCloud is a "cloudy" service, and works entirely without JSON.)

Comment: Aha yes, I have not started my server back end but will probably be .Net, node or go, and a doc db or graph db. Not sure how that would benefit from using iCloud?

Comment: I don't understand then; in your question, you say "restoring them from file." Is this designed to handle a file or an API? If it's a JSON API that you haven't written yet, then I would assume you would just add a type name to the JSON. If UA/UB/UC have exactly the same properties, then how would you possibly distinguish them in JSON? You would have to add something.

Comment: Well, my question is about initializing arbitrary subclasses from json, and not about why I chose json. Currently this json is on file, and I design for it to also go to and from an API in the future. See my answer below for a solution that worked for me. I appreciate your comments and will look into them.

Answer (score 1):

For init class from json I used this technic :

```
        //For row in json
        for row in json {
            //namespace it use for init class
            let namespace = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
            //create instance of your class
            if let myClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(row.name)") as? NameProtocol.Type{
                //init your class
                let classInit : NameProtocol = myClass.init(myArgument: "Hey")
                //classInit is up for use
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, so with this technique I would store the namespace and class name inside of the Unit json?

Comment: @JOG You need store only class name, for example : 

[ 
{"name": "MyClassA", "init": "Horus" },
{"name": "MyClassB", "init": "JOG" }
]

Comment: Could you please explain the NameProtocol.Type part of your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Store every Unit json with its classname

```
func asDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    let className = String(describing: type(of: self))

    let d = Dictionary<String, Any>(
        dictionaryLiteral:
        ("className", className),

        ("someUnitData", someUnitData),
        // and so on, for all the data of Unit...
```

And init from json with @horusdunord's solution:

```
for unitJson in unitsJson {

        let className = (unitJson as! [String: Any])["className"] as? String
        let namespace = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
        if let unitSubclass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(className ?? "N/A")") as? UnitProtocol.Type {

            if let unit = unitSubclass.init(json: unitJson as! [String : Any]) {
                units.append(unit)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

The trick here is that casting the class `unitSubclass` to `UnitProtocol` then allows you to call its `init(json)` declared in that protocol but implemented in the particular subclass, or in its superclass `Unit`, if the properties are all the same.

Comment: This is very, very dangerous. Never create classes base on data you received from an API. This is a very classic vulnerability. You should know what classes your system handles. Create a dictionary of JSON names to types. (If that's unclear, I'll write an example.) never call `NSClassFromString` on something you received over the network.

Comment: Aha, you mean to check that the className is one of the ones I expect it to be?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you can be handed something arbitrary that happens to respond to a method that you call. This is a really common exploit in the Java world (where deserializing arbitrary things from the network is common).

Comment: Impressive catch. So, I am going to need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42749141/237509 to list all the classes implementing my UnitProtocol, right?

Comment: No; nothing like that. Make a dictionary. `let classes = [ "Something": Something.Self, "Other": Other.Self]`. That way if you change the name of a class in your code, it won't break the JSON.

Comment: Ok the only overhead would be to manually add to that dict for every subclass I'd make of any Protocol.

Comment: Just anything you actually can serialize (if this is massive, you should rethink your class hierarchy). But it's pretty critical as a security measure, and it makes your system extremely flexible in the future.

Comment: (And there is a somewhat common pattern of using a "register" method to update the dictionary so that classes can register themselves. If they're `NSObject` subclasses, then you can put that in `+load` and it'll automatically run at the beginning of the program. But often this overkill; again, if it's incredibly complicated, you likely have too many classes.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your expertise! I learned quite some stuff. :)