# objc_copyClassList: crash EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION after update to iOS 13.4 / XCode 11.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

after updating to iOS 13.4 / XCode 11.4

this code

```
func getSubclassInfos() -> [ClassInfo] {
    let superObject = CityModel.self
    let superClassInfo = ClassInfo(superObject)

    var subclassList = [ClassInfo]()
    var count = UInt32(0)
    guard let classList = objc_copyClassList(&count) else {
        return subclassList
    }
    for i in 0..<Int(count) {
        let clazz = classList[i] // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
        if let classInfo = ClassInfo(classList[i]),
            let superclassInfo = classInfo.superclassInfo,
            superclassInfo == superClassInfo
        {
            subclassList.append(classInfo)
        }
    }

    return subclassList
}
```

crashes in line `let clazz = classList[i]` with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` in Simulator.

this line wasn't in my original code. It is here to show that the subscript crashes and not `ClassInfo(...)`

Any idea what I can do about it?

(the code is inspired by [List all subclasses of one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746981/list-all-subclasses-of-one-class))

Comment: Do you have the hardened runtime enabled? I think that limits some objc runtime capabilities, but I don't remember. Worth looking into. BTW you can simplify that whole `for` loop into just a simple `map` call.

Comment: No hardened runtime. (and yes, map would be more elegant. Old code of mine)

Comment: This (and the gist off of the other question fail for me in iOS 15 (runtime NOT hardened)). It access 2 elements of the list and then throws an exception :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just noticed: `classList` is a total misnomer. The returned result has type  `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>?`. Convert it to an `UnsafeBufferPointer<AnyClass>` first, and then do your processing on that:

```
func getSubclassInfos() -> [ClassInfo] {
    let superObject = CityModel.self
    let superClassInfo = ClassInfo(superObject)

    var count = UInt32(0)
    guard let classListPointer = objc_copyClassList(&count) else { return [] }

    return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: classListPointer, count: Int(count))
        .map(ClassInfo.init)
        .filter { $0 == superClassInfo }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks:         return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: classListPointer, count: Int(count))
            .compactMap(ClassInfo.init)
            .filter { $0.superclassInfo == superClassInfo }